# The usage of "recently" in the present tense

Tags: tense

The word "recently" occurs mostly with verbs in the simple past tense or the present perfect construction. But I found the following example in *Grammar for English Language Teachers*. Is it standard English?

> I seem to be getting more headaches recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is standard English.

In *I recently moved house*, the word means 'a short time ago'.

In *I seem to be getting more headaches recently*, it means 'in a short period of time before the present' (probably 'the past few weeks').

*I have been getting more headaches recently* would also be idiomatic.

Comment: What about "I'm getting more headaches recently"? Is this idiomatic too?

Comment: Yes, I think so.